# Neo4j browser: Display relationship property as edge label not working

Tags: visualization, neo4j

Is there a way to display relationship property as edge's label in Neo4j 2.0.1 Browser? It seems to work for nodes but not for edges.

Answer (score 2):

As of Neo4j 2.0.1 this is not supported. Properties can only be used as a caption on nodes.